# Method for arguments with gradle in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Syncing the project files with gradle files in android studio is resulting in the following error

```
Error:(14, 0) Could not find method applicationId() for arguments [com.amazon.mysampleapp] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

where the gradle file reads

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    applicationId "com.amazon.mysampleapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled = true
}
```

What is happening here? Removing applicationID moves the error to minSdkVersion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The applicationId doesn't go inside the android block, but instead your buildConfig block:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

Pulled that from this page about applicationId: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename